# Grunt Environment Variable Not Loading In Time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am using grunt-ng-constant to load environment variables into my angular application. This seems to be working 95% correctly with the exception of loading the application. For instance, when i load the app i cannot gain access to the variables, so if i log the ENV base object it comes up as undefined. If i navigate to the next page i am able to log the ENV and gain access to my vars. It seems to me that the app is loading prior to loading the config.js and i am unsure how to change this.

[image: Generating the config.js file]

**index.html**

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
 ....
```

**app.js**

```
    angular
    .module('serverSideConfiguratorApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'angularSpinner',
    'smart-table',
     'config'
  ])
```

**gruntfile**

```
 ngconstant: {
    qa: {
                  options: {
                      dest: 'app/scripts/config.js'
                  },
                  constants: {
                      ENV: {
                          name: 'qa',
                          server: [{
                              "name": "QA1 (232)",
                              "url": "http://xxxxx/"
                          }, {
                              "name": "QA2 (233)",
                              "url": "http://xxxxx/"
                          }, {
                              "name": "QA3 (LB)",
                              "url": "http://xxxxx//"
                          }]
                      }
                  }
              }
}
```

I have tried making config.js first in my index.html but that has no affect. If anyone can provide any insight it would be greatly appreciated! Also, if you need more code or have any questions let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suspected the answer was simple(and annoying). I did not know that injection order into a controller mattered so i had this:

```
angular.module('serverSideConfiguratorApp')
        .controller('ModelsCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', 'BaseURLService', 'configuratorService', '$q', '$timeout','$route', 'ENV',
                    function( $scope, $http, BaseURLService, configuratorService, $q, $timeout, ENV)
```

After changing to this (injecting ENV first):

```
angular.module('serverSideConfiguratorApp')
        .controller('ModelsCtrl', ['ENV', '$scope', '$http', 'BaseURLService', 'configuratorService', '$q', '$timeout','$route',
                    function(ENV, $scope, $http, BaseURLService, configuratorService, $q, $timeout)
```

everything now works fine!